# How can I set the horizontal spacing in HorizontalGridView?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

Whole Fragment layout: [Fragment layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GETpJ.png)

I want to separate the views so there would be 15dp of horizontal break between the cards, but now it looks like this : [Overlapped views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pejak.png)

I've already tried adding android:horizontalSpacing (like I would do this in regular GridView) attribute to the XML, but nothing happened. Using childrenOffsetHorizontal from LayoutManager also didn't give results as expected.

Here's the code of my Fragment:

```
public class TvDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

private HorizontalGridView gridView;
private SeasonsListAdapter seasonsListAdapter;

public TvDetailsFragment(){

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Get the arguments from  the ShowDetailsActivity.
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tv_details, container, false);
    gridView = (HorizontalGridView)rootView.
            findViewById(R.id.tv_details_seasons_gridview);
    gridView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    gridView.getLayoutManager().set

    FetchTvDetailsById fetchDetails = new FetchTvDetailsById(getContext());
    fetchDetails.execute(args.getString("SHOW_ID"));

    return rootView;
}

public void populateView(TvClass tvDetails) {

    Activity mActivity = getActivity();

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)mActivity.findViewById(R.id.tv_details_imageview);
    Picasso.with(mActivity).load(tvDetails.getShowPosterLink())
            .fit()
            .into(imageView);

    TextView titleView = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.tv_details_title_textview);
    titleView.setText( Html.fromHtml("<b>" + "Original title: " + "</b> <br>"
            + tvDetails.getShowOriginalTitle()));

    TextView dateView = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.tv_details_date_textview);
    dateView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + "Release date: " + "</b> <br>"
            + tvDetails.getShowReleaseDate()));

    TextView voteView = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.tv_details_vote_textview);
    voteView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + "Vote average: " + "</b> <br>"
            + Double.toString(tvDetails.getShowVoteAverage()) + "/10"));

    TextView overviewView = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.tv_details_overview_textview);
    overviewView.setText(tvDetails.getShowOverview());

    // Make the cards visible after loading the content.
    CardView posterCard = (CardView)mActivity.findViewById(R.id.tv_details_poster_card);
    posterCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    CardView infoCard = (CardView)mActivity.findViewById(R.id.tv_details_info_card);
    infoCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    CardView detailsCard = (CardView)mActivity.findViewById(R.id.tv_details_overview_card);
    detailsCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    ArrayList<ShowThumbnail> seasonThumbnails = tvDetails.getSeasonsThumbnails();
    seasonsListAdapter = new SeasonsListAdapter(getActivity(), seasonThumbnails);
    gridView.setAdapter(seasonsListAdapter);

    // Dismiss  the loading panel.
    RelativeLayout loadingPanel = (RelativeLayout)mActivity.findViewById(R.id.tv_details_loading_panel);
    loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```

fragment_tv_details.xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

<RelativeLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_tv_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:padding="20dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.mordowiciel.filmapp.Activity.ShowDetailsActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tv_details_loading_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Poster of a movie -->

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/tv_details_poster_card"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tv_details_imageview"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <!-- Linear layout for info on the right. Root linear layout is crucial for
         implementing MaxHeight attribute for CardView. (180dp.)
         If content in CardView >180dp in height, then the view is starting to act
         like scrollable.-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_details_poster_card">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/tv_details_info_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_details_title_textview"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="10dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_details_vote_textview"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="10dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_details_date_textview"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="10dp" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/tv_details_overview_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_details_poster_card"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_details_overview_textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <android.support.v17.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView
        android:id="@+id/tv_details_seasons_gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_details_overview_card"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center">
    </android.support.v17.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

image_item.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="230dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<RelativeLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_item_imageview"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/image_item_textview"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/image_item_imageview"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="Beniz"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And custom RecyclerView.Adapter:

```
public class SeasonsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SeasonsListAdapter.SeasonViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<ShowThumbnail> showThumbnailsList;
private Context ctx;

class SeasonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected ImageView imageView;
    protected TextView textView;

    public SeasonViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_item_imageview);
        this.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_item_textview);
    }
}

public SeasonsListAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<ShowThumbnail> showThumbnails) {
    this.showThumbnailsList = showThumbnails;
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public SeasonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_item, null);
    SeasonViewHolder seasonViewHolder = new SeasonViewHolder(view);
    return seasonViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder (SeasonViewHolder seasonViewHolder, int i) {

    ShowThumbnail showThumbnailItem = showThumbnailsList.get(i);
    Picasso.with(ctx).load(showThumbnailItem.getShowPosterLink())
            .fit()
            .into(seasonViewHolder.imageView);
    seasonViewHolder.textView.setText(showThumbnailItem.getShowTitle());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != showThumbnailsList ? showThumbnailsList.size() : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is wrong.
Add margin to your cards. not your Images. This will give the required spacing between cards!

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/tv_details_poster_card"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tv_details_imageview"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: That wouldn't be it, because tv_details_poster_card has nothing to do with the HorizontalGridView. I've edited my question so you could see how the whole Fragment layout looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it programmatically using `HorizontalGridView`'s [setHorizontalSpacing()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/HorizontalGridView.html#setHorizontalSpacing(int)) method?